# Check for missing time stamps in data

Tags: time-series, gfortran, missing-data

I am using gfortran. I have a small amount of experience with it (mostly scientific programming). I have an array of data (read in as characters) similar to the following:

```
12/1/2009 0:00  296 3161    -20.38
12/1/2009 1:00  297 3161    -20.18
12/1/2009 3:00  298 3161    -19.56
```

I want an automated program that can look at the time stamps and determine if one is missing based on a given expected time interval (for the example above, that would be 1 hour). I can think of ways to check for missing time stamps, but it involves writing a huge number of if statements, or a text file that has a list of all the time stamps for the past and future 5 years.

Is there some intrinsic function that can simplify this?

The data is in the form of  MM/DD/YYYY HR:MIN ... . I have a way to get the month, day, year, hour, and minute of the data. I don't know a useful way to compare the time stamps and determine if there are missing ones.

The end goal is to find where these missing time stamps are, fill them in, and place 'NAN' or blanks in the rest of the columns of that correspond to that time stamp.

```
12/1/2009 0:00  296 3161    -20.38
12/1/2009 1:00  297 3161    -20.18
12/1/2009 2:00
12/1/2009 3:00  298 3161    -19.56
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found this out. I can convert the year, month, day, hour, minute, and second to a Julian Day number.

I then convert the expected time difference to a Julian Day value (I say value as it's not technically a Julian Day number).

Subtract two consecutive Julian Day numbers. If their difference is not equal to the Julian Day value, there is a missing time stamp. Note, two duplicate time stamps ordered consecutively would be caught by this method.

I haven't determined a method to automatically correct this as other possible errors can appear.